# How to add an image to each choice of a choice list in a Symfony2 form?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I'm using Symfony 2 form to create an expanded choice list using radio buttons for selecting whether to post a blog as an anonymous user or not anonymous (showing username).

The form field type definition in the BlogType.php file looks like the following (I'm passing the choices with their values from the controller, but it should be irrelevant to my question):

```
$builder->add('is_anonymous', 'choice', array(
    'choices'   => $options['is_anonymous'],
    'required'  => true,
    'multiple'  => false,
    'expanded'  => true,
));
```

I tried to apply the ["How to customize an Individual field" section from the Symfony2 Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field) by  doing the following in my template twig file:

```
<div class="post_as">
    {{ form_label(form.is_anonymous, 'Post as:') }}
    {{ form_errors(form.is_anonymous) }}

    {% form_theme form _self %}
    {% block _factor_is_anonymous_0_label %}
        <img src="/images/anonymous-32.png"/>
        {{ block ('form_label') }}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block _factor_is_anonymous_1_label %}
        <img src="/images/user-32.png"/>
        {{ block ('form_label') }}
    {% endblock %}

    {{ form_widget(form.is_anonymous) }}
</div>
```

However, the above results in both images showing before the choice list in addition to each showing next to its corresponding radio button, as seen in the resulting html:

```
<div class="post_as">
    <label class="required">Post as:</label>
    <img src="/images/anonymous-32.png"/>
    <img src="/images/user-32.png"/>
    <div id="factor_is_anonymous">
        <input type="radio" id="factor_is_anonymous_0" name="factor[is_anonymous]" required="required" value="true" />
        <img src="/images/anonymous-32.png"/>
        <label for="factor_is_anonymous_0" class="required">Anonymous Collaborator</label>
        <input type="radio" id="factor_is_anonymous_1" name="factor[is_anonymous]" required="required" value="false" />
        <img src="/images/user-32.png"/>
        <label for="factor_is_anonymous_1" class="required">User Name</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get rid of the images from showing twice? I think this has to do with the images showing in the rendering of the overall choice "row" as well as in the rendering of each of the 2 choices. I tried various combinations for displaying the overall label and not, but I haven't been able to solve the issue... Could anyone help? thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the definitions for your form blocks **outside** of any other block. Ie, move these lines outside any other block, best would be at the beginning or end of file

```
{% block _factor_is_anonymous_0_label %}
    <img src="/images/anonymous-32.png"/>
    {{ block ('form_label') }}
{% endblock %}
{% block _factor_is_anonymous_1_label %}
    <img src="/images/user-32.png"/>
    {{ block ('form_label') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Good eye! Indeed, that was the problem! Thanks so much!

Comment: The trouble I'm having now is that I cannot access the "member" object in the block that is outside the "content" block that I'm including in the layout template. Accessing the "member" object would be needed if I want to display the specific member's image, though for example: <img src="/images/{{ member.Image }}"/>. Do you happen to know any work around for that? thanks again...

Comment: When these complex things happen, I usually end up rendering the form field by hand and not using form templates.

Comment: I'll keep your advice in mind @carlos-granados. The issue raised in my above comment is discussed at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763952/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-form-theme) and [this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3058). I'll have to see if the related commit from fabpot solves the issue...